# Can any type of file be transfered in Binary mode ? If yes, why we need the ASCII mode? Is there something that ASCII mode will be better?

Tags: file-transfer

When I want to transfer a file, I need to consider choosing which mode , ASCII mode or Binary mode ? And I see that if the file can be viewed in a text editor like notepad (ie. .html, .js, .css files etc), I should choose ASCII mode, most others (including images, sound files, video, zip files etc), I should choose Binary mode ? But I think any type of file could be transfer in Binary mode ? If yes, why we need ASCII mode ? Is it better when transfer files like text ?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about FTP file transfer modes, binary mode tranfers file as is.
Text mode converts line endings CRLF -> LF when tranfering from windows to unix for example.
It requires additional CPU power of FTP server to parse and replace line endings and many FTP servers do not support ascii transfer mode.

See also http://www.serv-u.com/newsletter/NewsL2008-03-18.asp

Comment: I see this "* pdf - PDF files can contain embedded binary data such as images". Does that mean the file may contain both ASCII data and binary data ? If yes, how can I transfer this file ?

Comment: You definitely have to transfer PDF files in binary mode as it will contain bianry data. It even usually contain some weird characters in comment line to make autodetection algorithms detect it as binary files. And exact "line ending" is stated in it's specification, wich will be broken if converted by ascii transfer. Also AFAIR embedded data streams should be compressed, producing binary chunks.

Comment: Anyway, if in doubt, it is almost always safe to use binary transfer mode. The only case i am aware is when transferring scripts to unix boxes - CRLF line ending will broke [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are transferring files across the internet.
Well you can transfer file in any format you want, but we normally use or have HTTP calls(requests) and hence the response is usually HTTP response and HTTP is preferred because it is a PURE TEXT BASED PROTOCOL(Hyper Text Transfer Protocol). No binary is transferred here.

Comment: In fact, I want to transfer files from the server to the client like FTP, and the file could contain text data or binary data or both.

Comment: then just use HTTP, it works fine!! Like I created a link to download a .pdf so in my servlet's doPost() , I did response.setContent("aplication/pdf") (can't remember exact syntax)so the browser understands that it should give an option to save the file on your hard disk. check file type and set the contentType of Response object.

Comment: If you don't add a type then it downloads everything as a Text file i.e. an HTML file, in this case after downloading file you have to do stuff like save extension as .pdf(In my case) right click open with Adobe Acrobat reader and stuff then it opens up. :p **Set the type so browser understands how to handle it.**

Comment: but actually, I want to use socket to write a program to simulate the function of FTP. So, I need to know what's the difference between the ASCII mode and Binary mode, not only download the file.

Comment: Oh I've never done that... search diff between ascii and binary mode transfer for FTP then you'll find many links on google... Sorry can't help you here dude.